# Copy a column by name from multiple Excel files which are saved in a specific folder and save it in csv

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy a column from all the Excel files(.xls) saved in a specific folder and append to a text file.

Selecting the column should be based on the column name, as the column number varies for every Excel file.

How can I create the script with this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Stack Columns

- This will copy the columns' values to a new (destination) workbook and save the workbook in the same folder as the folder of the workbook containing this code (`Thisworkbook`). The new workbook is named after the header (`Name.csv`).
- An improvement would be to write the values to a data structure (array, dictionary, or array list) and afterward to write its values to a text file in one go without ever having a destination workbook.
- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub StackColumns()
' Needs 'RefWorksheet', 'RefFirstOccurrenceInRow' and 'RefColumnDataRange'
    Const ProcTitle As String = "Stack Columns"
    
    ' Source
    Const sFolderPath As String = "C:\Test\"
    Const sFilePattern As String = "*.xls*"
    Const swsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const sHeader As String = "Name"
    Const shRow As Long = 1
    ' Destination
    Dim dFolderPath As String: dFolderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    Dim dBaseName As String: dBaseName = sHeader
    
    Dim sFileName As String: sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & sFilePattern)
    If Len(sFileName) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No files found.", vbCritical, ProcTitle
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim swb As Workbook
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim shCell As Range ' Header Cell
    Dim scdtrg As Range ' Column Data Range (no headers)
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet
    Dim dCell As Range
    Dim IsDestinationWorkbookAdded As Boolean
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Do Until Len(sFileName) = 0
        Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sFolderPath & sFileName)
        Set sws = RefWorksheet(swb, swsName)
        If Not sws Is Nothing Then ' worksheet found
            Set shCell = RefFirstOccurrenceInRow(sws.Rows(shRow), sHeader)
            If Not shCell Is Nothing Then ' header found
                Set scdtrg = RefColumnDataRange(shCell)
                If Not scdtrg Is Nothing Then ' found data in Column Data Range
                    If Not IsDestinationWorkbookAdded Then ' not yet added
                        Set dwb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
                        Set dws = Worksheets(1)
                        Set dCell = dws.Range("A1")
                        IsDestinationWorkbookAdded = True
                    'Else ' already added
                    End If
                    dCell.Resize(scdtrg.Rows.Count).Value = scdtrg.Value
                    Set dCell = dCell.Offset(scdtrg.Rows.Count)
                    Set scdtrg = Nothing
                'Else ' no data in Column Data Range
                End If
                Set shCell = Nothing
            'Else ' header not found
            End If
            Set sws = Nothing
        'Else ' worksheet not found
        End If
        swb.Close False
        sFileName = Dir
    Loop
    
    If Not dwb Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
        dwb.SaveAs dFolderPath & dBaseName & ".csv", xlCSV
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        'dwb.FollowHyperlink dFolderPath ' explore the Destination Path
        'dwb.Close
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Columns stacked.", vbInformation, ProcTitle
    
End Sub


Function RefWorksheet( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook, _
    ByVal WorksheetName As String) _
As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set RefWorksheet = wb.Worksheets(WorksheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function


Function RefFirstOccurrenceInRow( _
    ByVal RowRange As Range, _
    ByVal SearchString As String) _
As Range
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    With RowRange.Rows(1)
        Set RefFirstOccurrenceInRow _
            = .Find(SearchString, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlFormulas, xlWhole)
    End With
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Resume ProcExit
End Function


Function RefColumnDataRange( _
    ByVal HeaderCell As Range) _
As Range
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    With HeaderCell.Cells(1)
        With .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row).Offset(1)
            Dim lCell As Range
            Set lCell = .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
            Set RefColumnDataRange = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
        End With
    End With
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```